# Create CSV file of deleted users from active directory

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Got the following code, I can created the CSV file of users, but would like it to be only populated by the users that will get deleted from the loop above it. Just not saw how to integrate both together.
Basically, its pulls all users that will get deleted that are 90 days + old, then the users information gets put in to a CSV.

```
$OU='OU=Users,OU=Test,DC=corporate,DC=domain,DC=com'

$LISTOFACCOUNTS=Get-ADUser -Property lastlogondate -SearchBase $OU -Filter {lastLogonDate -lt $NumberDays}

$LISTOFACCOUNTS | DISABLE-ADACCOUNT -WhatIf

$LISTOFPOTENTIALDELETES=Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -Property Lastlogondate -Filter` {lastlogondate -lt $DeleteDate}

FOREACH ($USER in $LISTOFPOTENTIALDELETES) { 

    IF (($USER.Notes -notlike '*'+$OVERRIDE+'*') -and ($USER.Description -notlike` '*'+$OnLeave+'*')) 
    { 
        WRITE-HOST $USER.SamAccountName 'Deleted' 
        REMOVE-ADOBJECT $USER.SamAccountName -whatif 
    } 
    ELSEIF ($USER.Notes -like '*'+$OVERRIDE+'*') 
        { 
            WRITE-HOST $USER.SamAccountName 'Not removed due to Administrative Override'  
         } 
        ELSE 
        { 
            WRITE-HOST $USER.SamAccountName 'Not removed - Presently on Leave' 
        } 
} 

$memberOf = @{n='MemberOf';e={ ($_.MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1') -join ';' }}
$LastLogonDays = @{N='Last Logon Days'; E={$($(Get-Date) - ` $([DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon))).Days}}
$LastLogon = @{N='LastLogon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
$Mail =  @{ Name = 'mail'; Expression = { $_.mail -join ';'; }; }
$Description = @{N='Description'; E={$_.description -join ';'; }; }

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties * | Select Enabled, SAMAccountName, ` CanonicalName, Displayname,Givenname, Surname, Department, `
ProfilePath, HomeDrive, $Description,  $LastLogonDays, $LastLogon, $mail, $memberOf | 
Export-CSV "E:\Temp\_DisabledUserList.csv"
```

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a list with the user objects before they're deleted:

```psh
$deletedUsers = @()
foreach ($USER in $LISTOFPOTENTIALDELETES) {
  if ($USER.Notes -notlike ...) { 
    Write-Host $USER.SamAccountName 'Deleted'
    $deletedUsers += $USER
    Remove-ADObject $USER.SamAccountName -WhatIf 
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

and export that list to a CSV:

```
$deletedUsers | select SamAccountName, ... | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\deleted.csv'
```

Side note: I'd recommend using `Remove-ADUser` instead of `Remove-ADObject` for removing AD users.

Comment: Just noticed that the IF statement is wrong in my code, it should have a '-or' not '-and' as there is no scenario where both is true. Cheers Ansgar nice work!